# android studio get time from chronometer and write to xml

Tags: java, android, xml, chronometer

I am working on an Android app using android studio. I want that if the user stops the chronometer, the chronometer will be reset, save the time and print it in XML format (text view). How can I do this? I am new to the Android studio. I hope I explained well the problem

Here is my java code

**TimerActivity class**

```java
public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button basla, bitir; 
    Chronometer kronometre;
    Animation rotate;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView x;
    long pause, base;
    //"basla" is start, "bitir" is stop
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
        ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        basla = findViewById(R.id.basla);
        bitir = findViewById(R.id.bitir);
        kronometre = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.yuvarlak);
        x = findViewById(R.id.x);
        // I have a chronometer animation, if i must publish animation code for my problem, i can.
        rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(TimerActivity.this, R.anim.rotation);
        basla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView.startAnimation(rotate);
                kronometre.setFormat("%s");
                kronometre.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-pause);
                kronometre.start();
                basla.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                bitir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        bitir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                kronometre.stop();
                kronometre.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                pause=0;
                rotate.cancel();
                imageView.setAnimation(rotate);
                basla.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bitir.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here is my **XML code**

```
<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/yuvarlak"
        android:textColor="@color/arkakplan"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30dp" />

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/yuvarlak"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/yuvarlak"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/basla"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/presmi"
        android:textColor="@color/arkakplan"
        android:text="Başla"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/bitir"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/presmi"
        android:textColor="@color/arkakplan"
        android:text="Bitir"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        />
```